# Paste Command Not Recognizing Linebreak (/n) In Script

Tags: linux, shell, unix, sed, command

I'm using the following code to prepend the header "Both" and a blank line to a file.

```
sed -i '1i Both \n' file1
```

When I open the file, I can see the line break.

However, when I paste the file using the following command, it removes the line break in shell.

```
paste file1 file2 | column -s $'\t' -t | sed '1i\\'
```

Anyone know why this isn't being recognized by paste?

To be more specific, the /n characters are being recognized, but paste will eliminate the newline if its in the same row.

What's being outputted:

```
Header1     Header2
abc         def
ghi         jkl
```

What should be:

```
Header1     Header2

abc         def
ghi         jkl
```

I know it removes the newline because when I only prepend a new line to one file, it looks like this:

```
Header1     Header2               
            def
abc         jkl
ghi
```

As a temporary workaround, I'm using `sed -i '1i Both \n----' file1` which forces paste to print the new line since it is not empty:

```
Header1     Header2
----        ----        
abc         def
ghi         jkl
```

And, it keeps the newline, so I guess, how can I preserve the new line in a row all the way across when pasting together two files?

Comment: can you post what you're getting and what you expected?

Comment: Just provided some more details.

Comment: In the meantime, I'm using `sed -i '1i Both \n----'` which forces the new line to be recognized because it is not empty and gives me a divider between headers and data.

Comment: Huh? "Recognized by `paste`"? You're doing this to the *output* of `paste`. `paste` can't see what's being done to its output; it has no way of interacting with that `sed` process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need for `sed` here. Observe:

```
# defining functions here to make this a standalone reproducer
# remove these and change <(file1) to just file1 to use files instead
file1() { printf '%s\n' Header1 abc ghi; }
file2() { printf '%s\n' Header2 def jkl; }

# use braces to create a code block, and redirect that whole block to your output file
{
  printf '%s\n' Both ''                        # header, then blank line
  paste <(file1) <(file2) | column -s $'\t' -t # body content
} >out.txt                                     # redirection
```

...obviously, if you aren't redirecting output to a file at all, you don't need the redirection, nor the block. This is also more efficient: There's no need for the output of `column` to be read and then written by `sed`.